# map search react inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

hey all i have this table in database

```
st_ID    firstName    LastName  Classes
  1         paul       adams      php
  1         paul      adams       javascript
  1         paul      adams       ASP
  2        Georges    wayne       PHP
```

so i want to have this result:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>FirstName</td>
      <td>LastName</td>
      <td>Classes</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>paul</td>
      <td>adams</td>
      <td>php, javascript,Asp</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

so i used map function from react

```
renderTable(testValue) {
  let arrayValue = [];
  let arrayID = '';

  map(testValue,  (x) => {
    if (!arrayID){
      arrayID = x.st_ID
    }
    else{
      if (arrayID === x.st_ID){
        // here iw ant to show all classes with same st_ID
      }
      else{
        // here i want to show classes of next st_ID
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of testValue look like

Comment: @eddy there is no `map function from React` as you mentioned, React is javascript and map is a method applying on arrays. I'm not helping but only trying to clarify ! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You will need somehow to group your objects as follows

```
var helper = {};
var result = arr.reduce(function(r, o) {
  var key = o.FirstName + '-' + o.LastName;

  if(!helper[key]) {
    helper[key] = Object.assign({}, o); // create a copy of o
    r.push(helper[key]);
  } else {
    helper[key].ClassName +=","+ o.ClassName;
  }

  return r;
}, []);
```

we are consecutively checking for existing keys and pushing them in our helper object. Where classname is separated by comma.

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/z7fsL0ny/1/) for example

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution, hope this help ...

```js
    let testValue = [
      {
        st_ID: 1,
        firstName: 'paul',
        LastName: 'adams',
        Classes: 'php'
      },
      {
        st_ID: 1,
        firstName: 'paul',
        LastName: 'adams',
        Classes: 'JS'
      },
      {
        st_ID: 1,
        firstName: 'paul',
        LastName: 'adams',
        Classes: 'ASP'
      },
      {
        st_ID: 2,
        firstName: 'Georges',
        LastName: 'wayne',
        Classes: 'php'
      }
    ]
    
    
    let data = [];
    Array.from(new Set(testValue.map(obj => obj.st_ID))).forEach(id => {
      let isFirstTime:boolean = true;

      testValue.filter((el) => {
        return (el.st_ID == id)
      }).forEach(obj => {

        // check first !
        if (isFirstTime) {
          data.push(obj);
          isFirstTime = false;
        }else {
          data[data.length -1].Classes += ',' + obj.Classes;
        }
      });

    });
    console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way your data is organised, I suggest to iterate over it first in order to have a better structure to map over.

In this example I assume your data looks like the following once you have extracted it from your database.

```
const databaseData = [
  {
    st_ID: 1,
    firstName: 'paul',
    lastName: 'adams',
    classes: 'php'
  }, {
    st_ID: 1,
    firstName: 'paul',
    lastName: 'adams',
    classes: 'JS'
  }
]
```

First iteration: Assign each skill to the individual. One way to achieve this is by using the [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) array function.

```
const combineClasses = data.reduce((collect, {st_ID, firstName, lastName, classes}) => {
  if (collect[st_ID]) {
    classes = [...collect[st_ID].classes, classes]
    return {...collect, [st_ID]: {...collect[st_ID], classes}}
  } else {
    return {...collect, [st_ID]: {firstName, lastName, classes: [classes]}}
  }
}, {});
```

What's the code doing?

1. Iterate over each item in data
2. If the individual is present, add the value in classes to the array in the object for them.
3. If not, add the id as the key in the object and add firstname, lastname and the class (in an array).

Second iteration: Now that you have your data organised and skills are listed per individual, it will be much easier to map over. For example.

```
<tbody>
  { Object.keys(combineClasses).map((key) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{combineClasses[key].firstName}</td>
        <td>{combineClasses[key].lastName}</td>
        <td>{combineClasses[key].classes.join(', ')}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  })}
</tbody>
```

Obviously you'll need code to display the full table and include heading. You'll find a working example below.
https://codepen.io/roycode/pen/vaGoGR?editors=0010